# How can I reliably create latex classes in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf

I'm trying to modify my `.emacs` to create my own classes,

I tried [this article](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/04/nice-looking-pdfs-with-org-mode-and.html) and using `org-latex` rather than `ox`.

I also tried [this different approach](http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/org-mode-basics-v-exporting-your-notes/).

I tried enclosing the above classes with `with-eval-after-load 'org-latex` as suggested in another post.

Yet I can't seem to have my classes working when I input : `#+LATEX_CLASS: myclass` in an org file. (In my case, `#+LATEX_CLASS: notes`)

Using either "notes" or "article" in the `\documentclass{}` does not change anything.

I only get the same message all the time :

```
user-error: Unknown LaTeX class ‘notes’
```

N.B : Here is my [init file](https://pastebin.com/0CNZvbtF)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your init file defines a `notes` class that can be used by org when exporting to LaTeX:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: notes
```

It works fine, in the sense that it produces a latex output that starts out like this:

```
\documentclass{notes}
   ...
```

But then, the org exporter calls `pdflatex` (or `xelatex` or something else depending on your setup) to process the LaTeX file. And guess what: `pdflatex` chokes because *there is no `notes.cls` class file*. `pdflatex` returns an error and org duly reports it. IOW, this is a problem that *LaTeX* encounters; the org exporter is just the bearer of the bad news.

Note that in your second link, the author defines a class `bjmarticle` that can be
used with the `#+LATEX_CLASS` directive in the org file, but that is defined in terms of the standard `article` LaTeX class:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("bjmarticle"
               "\\documentclass{article}
               ...rest elided...
```

so the LaTeX file that is produced starts with

```
\documentclass{article}
  ...
```

which causes no problems: the LaTeX processor knows about the `article` class.

So you either have to define your org-mode `notes` class in terms of a LaTeX class that exists on your system or install a `notes` class into your LaTeX installation
(assuming that such a class exists).

BTW, unless your org mode installation is really old, you need `ox-latex`, not `org-latex` in your init file:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
               '("notes"
         "\\documentclass{notes}
                  ...
```

The blog posts you found are from 2011 and 2015 resp. and `org mode` has changed substantially since then. Because of that, it's always a good idea to report your version - just do:

```
M-x org-version
```

and add it to your question.

EDIT: Here are some debugging hints:

- If you are on Linux (or some sort of Unix system), then `kpsewhich` can tell you whether a LaTeX class exists on your system:

```
$ kpsewhich article.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
$ kpsewhich notes.cls
$
```

I don't know if that's available on Windows.

- When you export an org file `foo.org` to PDF, a LaTeX file `foo.tex` is produced. You can try to process that file on the command line and see if you get errors:

```
pdflatex foo.tex
```

You might need to add the `--shell-escape` option, depending on your setup:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape foo.tex
```

- When the exporter tries to export to PDF, the output of the LaTeX processor ends up in an emacs buffer called `*Org PDF LaTeX Output*` which you can visit with `C-x b`. That's another way to see whether there are errors in the LaTeX processing.

Comment: Thanks to you I went back to my file and changed it to `ox-latex`, updates all packages. I'm using org 9.1 something. I exported to Latex and worked my way from there, reading the log.

Thanks again !

Comment: Glad it helped!